# how to sign Android device out of Google account temporarily

Tags: google-account

How can I - from my Android device - temporarily sign the device out of a Google account?  I'm running Android 6.0.1 on a Galaxy Note 4.

If I go to Settings > Accounts > Google > tap specific account > three dots menu - there is a "Remove Account" option.  But I don't want to remove the account from the device, I just want to sign out of the account temporarily, and sign back in later.  I suspect that "remove account" does a lot more than just signing out of the account.

I can do it from my PC - myaccount.google.com > "device activity & security events" > "review devices" > click specific device > Account Access: REMOVE button.  This  does not remove the account from the device.  It just signs the device out of the Google account.  It takes one tap to sign the device back into the Google Account.

Comment: may I ask why? if you can, depending on why, you may be able to make a new user and then do whatever under that user. or, you can add another account and tell Google apps to use the other account

Comment: Wild guessing: You could try to "logout" via the GMail app (or the Playstore app), which uses the same account. Not sure whether that logs out the entire device or just the single app – but I'd suspect the former (after all, if signed in once from "anywhere", GMail doesn't ask for credentials). No promise, but worth a try.

Comment: @pcs3rd my main concern is to log out of Google Maps location sharing for awhile - I thought I had turned off location sharing but somehow it got reactivated without me doing it intentionally - so I was thinking a sure way to preventhat from happening would be to log out of the Google account altogether.

Answer (score 0):

In android removing the account is equivalent to that of logging out in PC. As lots of data is being synced from your google accounts to your phone therefore if you remove the account from your phone the data which is already synced won't be affected, But you won't be able to use any google related services in your phone.

Apart from that there won't be any problem.

Comment: Hi @Biman, I started to give it a try, but when I tapped "Remove Account" in the three dots menu, I got this message - "Removing the account will delete all of its messages, contacts, and other data from the phone. Continue?"  That's what I was afraid of!  If I do "Remove Device" from a PC, that doesn't happen.  It sounds like if I "Remove Account" from the phone, when I add the account back to the phone all of its data would have to be re-synced.